# ASP.NET Redirect to another website based on URL pattern

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, iis

I have an ASP.NET application (WebForms) **A** which serves **mycompany.com** URL.

I need to host new website (ASP.NET MVC) **B** on the same IIS, which serves **mycompany.com/B/...** pattern.

Main objective here is that, we want to keep mycompany.com domain in URL for branding issues.

How can I manage this?

The scenarios I already tried:

- I defined mycompany.com/B pattern on load balancer, so that balancer can redirect specific request to my website B. In this scenario, webpage load was successful however resource files such as css, js, etc failed to load because they tried to load from mycompany.com insted of mycompany.com/B.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure B as a virtual directory in A. In IIS manager, right-click on A, choose "Add application.." and configure B from the dialog you get.

Then, the B application will know that it is not a root application, and all helper methods in MVC that generate URLs will add the correct prefix (for example, `Url.Action` or will give you a url starting with `/B/`). With methods that take a URL as parameter (like `Url.Content`), you'll need to use a virtual URL, starting with `~/`.

Comment: Riokmij, thanks for your reply but we do not want to create virtual directories. We want to add new website on IIS.